# is there a way to get only the nodes in the deepest layer?

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I have a graph with 'person' nodes, a basic relation of 'parent-child' between some nodes, and a transitive 'descendant' relation.

for a specific 'person' I'd like get the oldest 'grandparents' the graph knows about ONLY.
which means - they do not play the 'child' for any other node.

what would be a good way to achieve that?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- Each node have 2 parents
- Graph is acyclic

First, read all edges and add two parents into `parent` dictionary. So that `parent[some_id]` will have two parents.
Then call a recursive function like this:

```py
def get_grandpa_age(x):
  if not parent[x.id]:
    return x.age
  mother_side = get_grandpa_age(parent[x.id][0])
  fathers_side = get_grandpa_age(parent[x.id][1])
  return max(mothers_side, fathers_side)

get_grandpa_age(some_entity)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a  Grakn rule to create transitive links firstly:

```
transitive-parentship sub rule, when {
  (ancestor: $p, descendant: $c) isa ancestorship;
  (ancestor: $c, descendant: $x) isa ancestorship;
}, then {
  (ancestor: $p, descendant: $x) isa ancestorship;
}
```

then, at read time you can use negation to find the oldest ancestor of a person:

```
match 
  $p isa person, has name "John Smit";
  (ancestor: $ancient, descendant: $p) isa ancestorship;
  not { (ancestor: $evenolder, descendant: $ancient) isa ancestorship; };
get $p, $ancient;
```

This will find the oldest ancestor that doesn't have another ancestor. Note this requires an acylclic graph!